# Power shell Invoke-Command NotSpecified: (The directory name is invalid.:String) [], RemoteException error

Tags: powershell, invoke-command, remoteexception

I am trying to run the following Invoke-Command that will run rabbitmq-service.bat on a remote computer with "remove" parameter. The command is executing perfectly with removing the rabbmitmq-service but with the following error "The directory name is invalid."

```
$Cre = Get-Credential -Message "Enter credentials for $fo1"
$fo1Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName Dedicated-Test1 -Credential $Cre
$action = "C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.10\sbin\rabbitmq-service.bat"
$remove = "remove"

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>  Invoke-Command -Session $fo1Session -ScriptBlock {& $using:action $using:remove -verb runAs} 

The directory name is invalid.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The directory name is invalid.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : Dedicated-Test1

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
C:\Program Files\erl10.2\erts-10.2\bin\erlsrv: Service RabbitMQ removed from system.
```

Comment: What's the value of `$using`?

Comment: I am using $using for a local variable to execute on the remote machines.

Comment: Does that contain the computer list?

Comment: I need to run "C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.10\sbin\rabbitmq-service.bat" with "remove" parameter on remote machine. any sample code would really help me.  I am sure the path is OK on the remote machine.

Comment: @WasifHasan no, I have only one remote computer in $fo1Session.

Comment: @WasifHasan I tried your code and the error is "Invoke-Command : Cannot bind parameter 'ScriptBlock'. Cannot convert the "& {new-item -path 'C:\Batch.Bat' -type file -value echo off"

Comment: It looks like it is something inside the batch file that triggers this error. It is usually seen when the working directory is set to a path that the executing user isn't permitted to access. How does `-Verb Runas` come into play here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code without $using:

```
$batch = get-content $action -raw
invoke-command -computername TheRemoteComputer -session $fo1session -scriptblock "& {new-item -path 'C:\Batch.Bat' -type file -value $batch; cmd.exe /c 'C:\Batch.bat $remove'; remove-item 'C:\Batch.bat'}"
```

Replace TheComputerName with the remote computer's name.

Comment: $batch = get-content $action -raw invoke-command -computername Dedicated-Test1 -session $fo1session -scriptblock "& {new-item -path 'C:\Batch.Bat' -type file -value $batch; cmd.exe /c 'C:\Batch.bat $remove'; remove-item 'C:\Batch.bat'}"

Invoke-Command : Cannot bind parameter 'ScriptBlock'. Cannot convert the "& {new-item -path 'C:\Batch.Bat' -type file -value @echo off